# VBA Dir() execution refreshes?

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a main Sub, in which I placed Dir() function so as to loop through files in selected folder (files are directed to particular Subs due to their extension). One of the formats is Outlook e-mail (.msg) and the macro extracts then Workbooks and operates on them, and in the end deletes extracted Workbooks. But (*this is my issue*), the macro requires to operate on the attachments, although the were deleted. It look like Dir() function embraces these attachments, too, but Dir() instruction of gathering files was executed in the beginning of main Sub (it is not placed in a loop).

I don't know how to delete the attachments and also preserve first files collection.

Here is the code below.
In a main Sub:

```
dirfilename = Dir(strfilename & "\")
'Do the loop for all files in a folder
Do While dirfilename <> ""
    If InStr(1, dirfilename, ".xls", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        update_Excel_files strfilename, dirfilename, mistakes_table_name, counter
    ElseIf InStr(1, dirfilename, ".msg", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        update_Emails strfilename, dirfilename, mistakes_table_name, counter
    End If
    dirfilename = Dir
Loop
```

And then I use Kill() function just at the end of Sub 'update_Emails'.

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution One**

Make a backup of all .msg files before doing the processing/extracting

```
Sub main()
  .
  .
  .
  dirfilename = Dir(strfilename & "\")
  'Make a backup of all the .msg files
  MkDir(strfilename & "\backUP")
  FileCopy(strfilename & "\*.msg", strfilename & "\backUP\.")
  'Do the loop for all files in a folder
  Do While dirfilename <> ""
    If InStr(1, dirfilename, ".xls", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
      update_Excel_files strfilename, dirfilename, mistakes_table_name, counter
    ElseIf InStr(1, dirfilename, ".msg", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
      update_Emails strfilename, dirfilename, mistakes_table_name, counter
    End If
    dirfilename = Dir
  Loop
  .
  .
  'MAKE SURE YOU CLEAN UP AT THE END OF MAIN SUB
  Kill(strfilename & "\backUP\*.*")
  RmDir(strfilename & "\backUP")
End Sub

Sub update_Emails(strfilename As String, dirfilename As String, mistakes_table_name As String, counter As Integer)
  .
  .
  .
  'PROCESS ON .MSG FILES FROM <<strfilename & "\backUP">>
  .
  .
  .
End Sub
```

**Solution Two**

Make a backup of .msg as and when they are processed. This way there is only one copy of the file at any given point of time.

```
Sub main()
  MkDir(strfilename & "\backUP")
  .
  .
  .
  Kill(strfilename & "\backUP\*.*")
  RmDir(strfilename & "\backUP")
End Sub
Sub update_Emails(strfilename As String, dirfilename As String, mistakes_table_name As String, counter As Integer)
  .
  .
  'PROCESS ANY OLDER .MSG FILES FROM BAKCUP FOLDER
  .
  .
  .
  'MAKE A BACKUP OF THE FILE BEFORE IT IS KILLED
  FileCopy(strfilename & "\" & dirfilename, strfilename & "\backUP\.")
  Kill(strfilename & "\" & dirfilename)
End Sub
```

I have not put in any Error handling but please do the needful.

**Edited**

I believe you are using `Dir` function inside the `update_Emails` sub. See below for a summary of how `Dir` works..
 1. `Dir(<dir_name or file_match_string>)` --> This resets the `Dir` Status to list files from start.
 2. A subsequent call to `Dir()` will list the next file in the list collected from step *1*
 3. `Dir` returns empty string **once** when there are no more files to return like in *2*
 4. `Dir` will go out of scope after *3* and will throw an error till you do step *1* again

**If you do step  `1` at any stage of a `Dir()` function call then you reset the Status to list files from start**(Is essence you disturb the state of `Dir` in `main` Sub if you call `Dir(<dir_name>)` anytime in  `update_Emails` Sub)

I believe you are having to re-use `Dir` (within `update_Emails` Sub) in middle of another `Dir` (in `main` Sub) so I would do the below:-

**Solution Three**

```
Sub main()
  .
  .
  .
  Dim origFileList as Collection
  dirfilename = Dir(strfilename & "\")
  While dirfilename <> ""
    origFileList.add(dirfilename)
    dirfilename=Dir()
  End While
  'Make a backup of all the .msg files
  MkDir(strfilename & "\backUP")
  FileCopy(strfilename & "\*.msg", strfilename & "\backUP\.")
  'Do the loop for all files in a folder
  For Each dirfilename in origFileList
    If InStr(1, dirfilename, ".xls", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
      update_Excel_files strfilename, dirfilename, mistakes_table_name, counter
    ElseIf InStr(1, dirfilename, ".msg", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
      update_Emails strfilename, dirfilename, mistakes_table_name, counter
    End If
    dirfilename = Dir
  Next dirfilename
  .
  .
  'MAKE SURE YOU CLEAN UP AT THE END OF MAIN SUB
  Kill(strfilename & "\backUP\*.*")
  RmDir(strfilename & "\backUP")
End Sub

Sub update_Emails(strfilename As String, dirfilename As String, mistakes_table_name As String, counter As Integer)
  .
  'HERE YOU CAN USE DIR as NOW IT WILL NOT INTERFERE WITH Dir State in main
  .
  'PROCESS ON .MSG FILES FROM <<strfilename & "\backUP">>
  .
  .
  .
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal to answer my question. I am going to implement it. Could you explain me, why after deleting attachments Dir()'s collection changes?

Comment: @MaciejDrozdowski I've edited my answer to reflect your concerns. The short answer is `Dir()` collection is not changing because you deleted something, but it is changing due to a new call to `Dir(<dir>)` as the status resets.

Comment: I checked contents of 'update_emails' and 'update_Excel_files', and there is no more Dir call. The last one is just before 'while' loop as presented in my question post.

Comment: @MaciejDrozdowski can you let me know exactly what you mean by **"Dir() collection changes"**? How did you decide that `Dir()` collection changed?